# Is there a way to include variables in a salt log statement?

Tags: variables, logging, salt-stack

Is there a way to include variables in a salt log statement?

Code that I have:

```
{%- set myname = 'John Doe' -%}
{%- do salt.log.info("My name is {{ myname }}") -%}
```

I expect the salt logs to print:
`My name is John Doe` or `My name is 'John Doe'`

But what I get is:
`My name is {{ myname }}`

Answer (score 0):

The Jinja `{{ .. }}` delimiters for variable interpolation are not required here as the entire expression is already in a Jinja context `{% .. %}`.

We can use `~` to add (concatenate) the value of `myname` variable to the text. Like below:

```
{%- set myname = 'John Doe' %}
{%- do salt.log.info("My name is " ~ myname) %}
```

This will result in a log as expected:

```
My name is John Doe
```